# jQuery Datatable functionality not working when table data is populated by using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

**A] Problem Summary:**

Data for jquery datatable is being generated using javascript function which parses JSON data returned by python. 
Resultant HTML Table in the browser shows up correctly, but jquery datatable cannot recognize the data and datatable functionality is not working. When I look at the HTML Page source, I cannot see the data in the table either.

**B] Code excerpts:**

**1) jQuery datatable setup:**

```
/* Define two custom functions (asc and desc) for string sorting */
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['string-case-asc']  = function(x,y) {
    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['string-case-desc'] = function(x,y) {
    return ((x < y) ?  1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#datatable_for_current_users').dataTable( {
        "aaSorting": [ [3,'desc'] ],
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            { "sType": 'string-case' },
            null
        ]
    });

});
```

**2) HTML table setup for the jQuery datatable:**

```
<div id="your_city">     
     <!-- Table containing the data to be printed--> 
     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="datatable_for_current_users">
         <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Reported at</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- contents of the tbody will be loaded by javascript method XXX -->  
        </tbody>
    </table>    

</div>
```

**3) Javascript that parses the JSON output returned from python and populates the “tbody” of the datatable:**

Here javascript sends users country and city to python code. Python code then finds out the database objects for the particular user and send out JSON data back to javascript.

```
$.post("/AjaxRequest", { 
        selected_country_name: $users_country,
        selected_city_name: $users_city  
    },
    function LoadUsersDatatable(data) {
        var tbody = $("#datatable_for_current_users > tbody").html(""); 
        jsonData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
            var citydata = jsonData[i];
            var rowText = "<tr class='gradeA'><td>" + citydata.city.country.country_name + "</td><td>" + citydata.city.city_name + "</td><td>" + citydata.status + "</td><td>" + citydata.date_time.ctime + "</td></tr>";
            $(rowText).appendTo(tbody);
        }
    }    
);
```

**4) When the HTML page is rendered, I check the “tbody” of the datatable and it is empty:**

```
    <tbody>
            <!-- contents of the tbody will be loaded by javascript method XXX -->  
        </tbody>
```

And to me this appears to be the problem

In the browser however, I see the table being loaded correctly, the datatable however shows 0 entries and search sort functionality empties the table

[image]

Comment: Still stumped on this. I am going to check how is html getting the data from when the source has nothing.

Comment: After a bit of debugging using firebug, i can see the <tbody> being loaded correctly with the rows, but "view source" is not showing the data which implies that datatable might not work with this technique. I am beginning to think this is how javascript works. Doing a bit more reading on it.

Comment: Found one soulution here, http://www.mccran.co.uk/index.cfm/2010/4/29/JQuery-Datatables-plugin-example-using-a-server-side-data-request-coldfusion. Will be trying this out today and will post the results.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than simply appending raw html to the table body, you must utilize DataTables `fnAddData` method for it to pick up the new rows.

So for you, your code would look something like this

```
var dt = $('#datatable_for_current_users').dataTable();
....

dt.fnAddData({DT_RowClass: 'gradeA', 0: citydata.city.country.country_name,  1: citydata.city.city_name, 2: citydata.status, 3: citydata.date_time.ctime}, true);
```

The `true` at the end simply redraws the table after you add the row. If you want, you can change that to `false` and call `dt.fnDraw();` after your loop is finished to add all the rows at once